# Python Clutter: Know when a timeline is done?

Tags: python, clutter

Is there any way to know when a timeline has finished in Python-Clutter, so that I can do something and then run another timeline? Can I use .join() on it like timers in PyGTK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's a signal - "completed".